# Aligning shapefiles from different ArcMap documents?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinate-system

I've been working on this one ArcMap document containing a shapefile of Hong Kong (HK) city. I've been adding lots of shapefiles to the city and creating mostly polygons(see below pic). I've made sure my data frame's coordinate system is the same as all the shapefiles in my document which is Hong_Kong_1980_Grid.

Then, I made a new arcmap document and imported an image which showed the vessel fairways of HK. I did not give the image a spatial reference as I can't figure out a way of doing it, but I'm not sure its necessary(?).Anyway, I digitized the fairways, again making sure they had the Hong_Kong_1980_Grid coordinate system. Then, I exported these shapefiles and made sure the coordinate system was the same as the data frame's. I then saved my document and opened back up the HK city ArcMap document. Then I imported the fairway shapefile into the document but found that they were not aligning although they have the same coordinate system. I can't seem to find a good answer online.

[image]

Comment: ArcGIS is not a CAD system. Map documents do not store data, only a list of data sources. If the shapefiles (which *do* store the data) don't align, there is no magic process to force alignment. You may have had an incorrect datum transformation, or the original data may have been inaccurate. More details of the exact process would be necessary to distinguish between the options.

Answer (score -2):

Do a `gdalinfo` on the raster image to see its coordinate system. You digitized your data to it but the coordinate systems may not be the same.

Comment: The asker makes no mention of using GDAL.